# Autocomplete for macros defined in FMT file (TexStudio)

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion, format-files

After creating a FMT file and using it in lieu of a very long preamble, TeXStudio no longer recognise custom commands and environments that were previously defined the preamble. Hence, it no longer list these in the autocomplete menu. These commands and environments are also flagged as wrong syntax.

Is there a way to make TS recognise these from the FMT file?

Comment: I don't think so, the autocomplete function is not so clever. It e.g. doesn't know that etoolbox commands are valid when you load biblatex. But you can activate the wordlists of packages permanantly in the options.

Comment: You should ask the maintainers of TXS for such things. Maybe you find some post regarding this topic here: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/

Comment: Same problem here. Activate the root document, then Options > Set Current Document As Explicit Root; this worked for me.